# Script for Google Sheets doesn't load

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here's the script:

```
function deletesheet(){
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var date0 = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 2 * MILLIS_PER_DAY)
  var dateM = Utilities.formatDate(date0, "GMT+1", "MM");
  var dateD = Utilities.formatDate(date0, "GMT+1", "dd");
  var date2 = dateD+dateM;
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(String(date2))
  Logger.log("The problem isint here")
  if(sheet.getRange(sheet.getMaxRows(),sheet.getMaxColumns()).isChecked()){
    Logger.log("True")
  }else{
    Logger.log("FAlsse")
  }
```

It doesn't even log "The problem isnt here".

Comment: Try adding a semicolon at the end of `var sheet = ...` line. Always 'close' your code lines with semicolons, or it will understand as if the rest of the code is on the same line.

Comment: Also, the function isn't properly closed.  You're missing a closing bracket at the end.  Right-clicking and selecting Format Document or using Shift+Alt+F may also help you identify where you're not nesting properly. Although it's not always technically necessary to close lines with semicolons, it makes your code more readable and makes it more likely that you're not making a simple error. Right now it's hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can only fix the typos / syntax errors as follows, adding the proper delimiters such as closing brackets and semicolons where applicable.

From the comments it is suggested to use the Apps Script IDE as an indicator of where do you have missing brackets/parenthesis, etc...

```
function deletesheet(){
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var date0 = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 2 * MILLIS_PER_DAY);
  var dateM = Utilities.formatDate(date0, "GMT+1", "MM");
  var dateD = Utilities.formatDate(date0, "GMT+1", "dd");
  var date2 = dateD+dateM;
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(String(date2));
  Logger.log("The problem isint here");
  if(sheet.getRange(sheet.getMaxRows(),sheet.getMaxColumns()).isChecked()){
    Logger.log("True");
  } else {
    Logger.log("FAlsse");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function lookingforcheckboxes(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dt = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()- 2);
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(Utilities.formatDate(dt, "GMT+ 1", "ddMM"))
  if(sh.getDataRange().isChecked()){
    Logger.log("True")
  }else{
    Logger.log("FAlsse")
  }
}
```